# Appending tuple to a MutableList of tuples is giving an error

Tags: scala, tuples, scala-collections

```
scala> val x = mutable.MutableList[(Int, Int)]()
x: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[(Int, Int)] = MutableList()

scala> x += (1, 2)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
found   : Int(1)
required: (Int, Int)
          x += (1, 2)
                ^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is interpreting it as if you're trying to call the `+=` method with 2 parameters (as opposed to one tuple parameter).

Try one of the following instead

```
x += ((1, 2))

val t = (1, 2)
x += t

x += 1 -> 2 //syntactic sugar for new tuple
```

Note that the compiler can't figure out that you're trying to call the method with a single tuple parameter because there are multiple `+=` overloads:

```
def +=(elem : A) : Growable.this.type
def +=(elem1 : A, elem2 : A, elems : A*) : Growable.this.type
```

Without the second overload here, the compiler could figure it out.  The following example may clarify:

```
class Foo {
    def bar(elem: (Int, Int)) = ()
    def baz(elem: (Int, Int)) = ()
    def baz(elem1: (Int, Int), elem2: (Int, Int)) = ()
}
```

Calling `bar` in the way you called `+=` now works, but with a warning:

```
foo.bar(2, 3) //No confounding overloads, so the compiler can figure out that we meant to use a tuple here
warning: Adapting argument list by creating a 2-tuple: this may not be what you want.
```

Calling `baz` in the way you called `+=` fails, with a similar error:

```
f.baz(3, 4)
error: type mismatch;
```

Comment: To be clear, `+=` is overloaded, taking either one element or 2+. Otherwise, you'd get tupling of the args and the syntax works.

Comment: Not nit-picking, but to avoid confusion, the warning is emitted under `-Ywarn-adapted-args` or `-Xlint`. Some adaptations are more evil than others.